# Return absolutely nothing when a row is null

Tags: sql-server, dotnetnuke

I am working with DotNetNuke on top of SQL Server 2008.
I am attempting to return absolutely nothing when the following code returns a NULL value. I do not want an empty row, I do not want "null" I want absolutely nothing. Is this even possible? I tried using COALESCE, but I am either missing something or it is not intended for this purpose.

```
DECLARE @Category table (Category varchar(15), Deleted bit)

INSERT INTO @Category (Category, Deleted)
SELECT 'Benefits', 0
UNION ALL
SELECT 'UR', 0
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Events', 1

DECLARE @Staff Table (DNNUserID int, InternalStaff bit, 
Deleted bit, InactiveStaff bit)

INSERT INTO @Staff (DNNUserID, InternalStaff, Deleted, InactiveStaff)
SELECT '556', 1, 0, 0
UNION ALL
SELECT '423', 0, 0, 0
UNION ALL
SELECT '111', 1, 0, 1
UNION ALL
SELECT '222', 1, 1, 0

SELECT Category FROM @Category WHERE Deleted = 0
UNION ALL
SELECT CASE WHEN '111' IN 
    (SELECT DnnUserID FROM @Staff WHERE Deleted = 0 AND 
    InactiveStaff = 0 AND InternalStaff = 1) 
    THEN 'Internal Use Only' 
ELSE NULL END
```

The variable tables are simply here for ease of use, there are two real tables of roughly the same name that I actually have to work with.

I cannot use a stored procedure to perform these actions, it must be a simple select statement or a scalar UDF so that the telerik controls we are using will understand it.

I do not have direct access to DNN's actual background (so I can't edit any of DNN or Telerik's code), just to the server, and can add the select statement to a Telerik control only through the primary DNN web interface.

The idea is that if an individual is an Internal member of the company that I work for, we see the main list from the Category table, plus the entry 'Internal Use Only' in a Dropdown. If someone else uses it, say, one of our client's staff members they see only the list from Category.

Is this viable?
I am trying not to use a function at the moment as I have no way of testing it in the live system (I am working from home today and the VPN is down), but if that is necessary I can and will test on my home database using the SQL above.

EDIT

I could use roughly this in a function:

```
DECLARE @DNNUserID int = 111

DECLARE @Category table (Category varchar(15), Deleted bit)

INSERT INTO @Category (Category, Deleted)
SELECT 'Benefits', 0
UNION ALL
SELECT 'UR', 0
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Events', 1

DECLARE @Staff Table (DNNUserID int, InternalStaff bit, Deleted bit, 
InactiveStaff bit)

INSERT INTO @Staff (DNNUserID, InternalStaff, Deleted, InactiveStaff)
SELECT '556', 1, 0, 0
UNION ALL
SELECT '423', 0, 0, 0
UNION ALL
SELECT '111', 1, 0, 1
UNION ALL
SELECT '222', 1, 1, 0

IF @DNNUserID NOT IN (SELECT DnnUserID FROM @Staff WHERE Deleted = 0 
AND InactiveStaff = 0 AND InternalStaff = 1)
    BEGIN
        SELECT Category FROM @Category WHERE Deleted = 0
    END
IF @DNNUserID IN (SELECT DnnUserID FROM @Staff WHERE Deleted = 0 
AND InactiveStaff = 0 AND InternalStaff = 1)
    BEGIN
        SELECT Category FROM @Category WHERE Deleted = 0
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'Internal Use Only'
    END
```

But! I would much rather find a way to do this without having to resort to a function is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Category table (Category varchar(15), Deleted bit)

INSERT INTO @Category (Category, Deleted)
SELECT 'Benefits', 0
UNION ALL
SELECT 'UR', 0
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Events', 1

DECLARE @Staff Table (DNNUserID int, InternalStaff bit, 
Deleted bit, InactiveStaff bit)

INSERT INTO @Staff (DNNUserID, InternalStaff, Deleted, InactiveStaff)
SELECT '556', 1, 0, 0
UNION ALL
SELECT '423', 0, 0, 0
UNION ALL
SELECT '111', 1, 0, 1
UNION ALL
SELECT '222', 1, 1, 0

SELECT Category FROM @Category WHERE Deleted = 0
UNION ALL
Select * from
(
SELECT CASE WHEN '111' IN 
    (SELECT DnnUserID FROM @Staff WHERE Deleted = 0 AND 
    InactiveStaff = 0 AND InternalStaff = 1) 
    THEN 'Internal Use Only' 
ELSE NULL END as ARow
) a 
where ARow is not null
```

Answer (score 1):

This may work for you.  The EXISTS sounds like it will fit what you're trying to do.

```
DECLARE @Category table (Category varchar(15), Deleted bit)

INSERT INTO @Category (Category, Deleted)
SELECT 'Benefits', 0
UNION ALL
SELECT 'UR', 0
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Events', 1

DECLARE @Staff Table (DNNUserID int, InternalStaff bit, 
Deleted bit, InactiveStaff bit)

INSERT INTO @Staff (DNNUserID, InternalStaff, Deleted, InactiveStaff)
SELECT '556', 1, 0, 0
UNION ALL
SELECT '423', 0, 0, 0
UNION ALL
SELECT '111', 1, 0, 1
UNION ALL
SELECT '222', 1, 1, 0

SELECT Category FROM @Category WHERE Deleted = 0
UNION ALL

SELECT 'Internal Use Only'
WHERE EXISTS
    (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM @Staff
    WHERE Deleted = 0 AND 
      InactiveStaff = 0 AND 
      InternalStaff = 1 AND
      DNNUserID = 111
    )
```

Comment: That would also work well. Thank you. I'll have to see which is quicker.
I've had to make one tweak to this code so that it will filter correctly.
SELECT 'Internal Use Only'
WHERE EXISTS
    (
    SELECT DnnUserID 
    FROM @Staff
    WHERE Deleted = 0 AND 
      InactiveStaff = 0 AND 
      InternalStaff = 1 AND
      DNNUserID = '556' /* This would of course be tied to the control on the page which contained the session variable for the current DNNUserID */
    )